# Found a strange hitbox bug in pygame. If the player dies in my game, the hitbox stays which creates some problems

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, pyscripter

I found the `sprite.kill()` method by messing around with what pygame had to offer. However, I found out that for some reason the hitbox of the player stays wherever the player was killed if I use this statement. This creates some issue's, for example, I'm using a death counter to track the player's death, and so say if I die on a spike, the hitbox will stay and therefore the death counter will keep adding up. My workaround with this was to set player's x and y pos at the corner of the game window, but the more I develop my game I realized that this will fix my problem.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

That is not a bug. If you have a reference to the a [`Sprite`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) object somewhere else than in a [`Group`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group), then the object stays still a live (of course), even if you [`kill`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite.kill) it. `kill` does not destroy the object, it just removes the object fora all Groups.
That causes the object is not updated through the [`pygame.sprite.Group.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.update) mechanism and all its attributes stay untouched.
If a [`Sprite`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) is not part of a `Group` then you have to update the object yourself. No one will change the attributes magically and of course the "hitbox stays"

A solution would be to override the `kill` method and to reset some attributes (like the hit box) in the derived class:

```py
class MySprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()  
        # [...]

    def kill(self):
        print("kill me")

        # reset some attributes
        # [...]

        # kill the sprite
        super().kill()
```

Comment: Sorry for not answering, could you explain what you mean by reference to the sprite other than in a group and what do you mean by updating the attributes?

Comment: @Yes Please learn the basics. 1. each variable is a reference to an object. If `player` is an instance of Sprite the variable `player` refers to the a Sprite object. 2. "updating the attributes" means changing the members (attribute) of the Sprite instance. In common that  is done by `pygame.sprite.Group.update()`. If the sprite is not in a group, then that can't happen.